# How to configure the Compose key on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, compose-key

In Ubuntu 14.10 and prior, I used to go to `gnome-control-center`, click Keyboard, and there was some "advanced" section with a list of checkboxes where I could set which key to use as the [Compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Ubuntu_with_Gnome_desktop). I used the Menu key, but that setting got destroyed with the upgrade, and the Menu key now opens a right-click menu.

However, in Ubuntu 15.04, `gnome-control-center` is gone, and when I manually install it using `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`, it only contains three options: Language Support, Printers, and Software & Updates. No Keyboard section in sight.

As you may have guessed, I'm not using the Unity desktop (but Xmonad). **What is the new recommended way to set which key is mapped to Compose?**

I'm not averse to editing configuration files, but Ubuntu has a way of breaking unsupported customizations in every new version, so I'd rather do this the "official" way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `unity-control-center -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Compose Key`.

Comment: Great, thanks! This would have answered the question... except I seem to have asked the wrong question, because it's already set to "Menu".

Comment: Asked http://askubuntu.com/questions/618202/using-menu-key-as-compose-key-in-ubuntu-15-04-pops-up-a-menu-instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is no official way. Install and open the dconf editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Go to `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` and change the entry for `xkb-options`, eg:

```
['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp','compose:menu']
```

Replace the value for menu in `'compose:menu'` if you need another one. You can an option from the list below. The changes are effective immediately.

More options are listed in the [xkeyboard-config manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html):

```
   +------------------------------------------------------+
   |Option                Description                     |
   +------------------------------------------------------+
   |compose:ralt          Right Alt                       |
   |compose:lwin          Left Win                        |
   |compose:lwin-altgr    3rd level of Left Win           |
   |compose:rwin          Right Win                       |
   |compose:rwin-altgr    3rd level of Right Win          |
   |compose:menu          Menu                            |
   |compose:menu-altgr    3rd level of Menu               |
   |compose:lctrl         Left Ctrl                       |
   |compose:lctrl-altgr   3rd level of Left Ctrl          |
   |compose:rctrl         Right Ctrl                      |
   |compose:rctrl-altgr   3rd level of Right Ctrl         |
   |compose:caps          Caps Lock                       |
   |compose:caps-altgr    3rd level of Caps Lock          |
   |compose:102           <Less/Greater>                  |
   |compose:102-altgr     3rd level of <Less/Greater>     |
   |compose:paus          Pause                           |
   |compose:prsc          PrtSc                           |
   |compose:sclk          Scroll Lock                     |
   |                                                      |
   +------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! However... there's already `'compose:menu'` in the list, so apparently it's not working (I'm still getting the right-click menu). Any ideas?

Comment: @Thomas Which right-click menu?

Comment: Whatever menu you'd get when right-clicking the mouse on the thing that currently has the keyboard focus. Just like Windows does it, basically.

Comment: @Thomas I thought you wanted to change the entry for "xkb-options"? Single click on `['compose:menu']`.

Answer (score 0):

If `unity-control-center -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Compose Key` (as suggested earlier by @mhansen) is `Disabled` and you cannot change it, installing `ubuntu-tweak-tool` will make it changeable. See also [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225253).